# Print from recursion combination with list in C

Tags: c, list, recursion

I want to understand the following code:

```
struct element{
   element *a1;
   element *a2;
   int value;
};

void main(){
    element e6 = { NULL, NULL, 6 };
    element e2 = { NULL, NULL, 2 };
    element e4 = { NULL, NULL, 4 };
    element e7 = { &e6, NULL, 7 };
    element e9 = { NULL, NULL, 9 };
    element e3 = { &e2, &e4, 3 };
    element e8 = { &e7, &e9, 8 };
    element e5 = { &e3, &e8, 5 };

   cout << CountList(&e5) << endl;

return;}

int CountList(element *e){
   int c=1;
   if(e){
      c=c+CountList(e->a1);
      c=c+CountList(e->a2);
      return c;}
    return 0;
}
```

the count is 8. But how can I understand the recursion line ??
my Idea was, that the Count must be 6, because the recursion function are called only 4 times. The Compiler says 8, which is already the correct solution. But why??

Answer (score 1):

This is a tree

```
            e5
           /  \
         e3    e8
        / \    / \
      e2  e4 e7   e9
              |
             e6
```

The recursive function starts from `e5`, calls itself with `e3` first, which in turn calls with `e2`, another call with NULL which returns (to `e2`).

From `e2` a call on the other side which is NULL also, then returns (to `e3`).

From `e3`, a call to `e4`, which has only NULL children and returns (to `e3`).

From there, `e3` returns to `e5`, which calls the other side (`e8`)...

Each non-NULL element counts itself as 1, added to the non-NULL children.

Which gives 8 total. The number of elements in the tree.

---

The number of calls to the recursive function is at least 8, to visit all children. If you count the calls with a NULL element (9), that makes a total number of calls of 17.

Comment: ohh, this is great description.  Thanks

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think it deserves it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really a list, but a kind of binary tree.

```
int CountList(element *e){
```

Here, you count the current element (1 item):

```
   int c=1;
   if(e){
```

Then you add the number of elements counted in the first subtree:

```
      c=c+CountList(e->a1);
```

And you add the number of elements counted in the second subtree:

```
      c=c+CountList(e->a2);
```

which totals to the whole number of elements:

```
      return c;
    }
```

If the current element is NULL (empty tree), then return `0`:

```
    return 0;
}
```

That's quite all about it.